# Population of a de-novo human colony in 1,000 years on an Earth-like planet

Tags: population, colonization, generation-ships

If a highly technologically advanced (and educated, healthy, genetically diverse, etc.) group of 200 people colonized a planet, how many people would there be 1,000 years later if the planet they colonize is much like earth, they have brought the required supplies (i.e. frozen embryos, frozen sperm, seeds)?

Comment: This is way too broad. How can we predict 1000 years of development on a planet we know very little about?

Comment: This seems to have been discussed before, too. I recall looking at generation numbers and population in a similar but better specified question.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Barbara. As Homannfan indicated, there are a lot of unknowns here. Factors like prevalence of disease, solar radiation levels, genetic disposition, and gravity-induced stress can all have an impact on fertility, birth rates, and life expectancy. If you would [edit] your question to include details about your world, I believe the community would appreciate it.

Comment: Y might expect 30'000'000 with 1.2% growth rate. But if they have tech to automatize process, artificial womb, cloning etc - any number can be expected, as example 10^22 peoples(for systems like ours) or how much they can get energy for. I highly recommend this YT channel [Isaac Arthur](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZFipeZtQM5CKUjx6grh54g/videos) to get grasp how things in future (and colonization) may look like. It's good source for hard scify setting stuff.

Comment: @Hohmannfan I certainly understand your point about a millennium of development. What I don't understand is your remark about "a planet we know very little about" because the OP's question says "the planet they colonize is much like earth". This suggests a planet not too dissimilar to Earth, not an alien planet. I'd assume this means between 95% and 99.99% earthlike, say, 99% to be generous to the OP. This is  a question about population dynamics.

Comment: @JDługosz The population question you mentioned is this http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/5186/what-is-a-reasonable-amount-of-population-growth-for-900-years?rq=1 While there are similarities. The base numbers and time-frame are different. Close, but not a duplicate, with a colony planet setting.

Comment: @Frostfyre What puzzles me is why are "there are a lot of unknowns here" when the OP says "the planet they colonize is much like earth". This suggests the factors listed would default to the same as Earth or close enough not to be different. The answers are about population growth & not planetary conditions. worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/5186/… demonstrates this can be dealt with on WB SE without being too broad.

Comment: Barbara, I found this comment to a first time question that was closed. It's applicable to your present situation. "Welcome to the site, it takes some time to get used to the rules regarding how to ask a question around here but you'll figure it out." You will have discovered you need 80 plus to comment. This makes any communication to get help to fix your problem effectively impossible. Being told to edit your question isn't exactly helpful. It's all I can suggest you do at the moment.

Comment: @Frostfyre Sorry the link probably won't work in my comment to you. The link in my comment to JDLugosz should though -- I hope.

Comment: To add to a4android's remark, try the **sandbox** on [meta].

Comment: @a4android "Much like Earth" does not mean identical. Of the four examples I listed, only one is dependent on the planet itself (gravity-induced stress). The others are biological or environmental, which are highly likely to be different from Earth today.

Comment: @Frostfyre I agree it doesn't mean identical. But it doesn't mean much like earth after nuclear apocalypse, for example, or earth ten million years ago. I can devise adverse factors for fertility on an earthlike planet, but that makes the question too broad and for no good reason. The sensible approach is to apply Ockham's Razor and not multiply unnecessary entities. Gravity much like earth's gravity. Factors much like earth's factors. Anything unlike earth only if the OP says so. I'm not arguing if the factors are right or not, do they help or hinder answering a population growth question.

Comment: @Frostfyre While we can argue about factors as above, that's not the most important aspect, you will find we are both on the side of angels in wanting WB SE to run well. For clarification, go here http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3773/reminder-to-close-voters and read my comments. You will then better understand where I'm coming from.